# Getting Error with Django Social Authentication

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I have been working on social authentication with my current project but i am getting an error which leads to two more errors depending on the social media platform am using to signing in.

Upon successful redirection from the social media platform, i get an error from my Custom Model Manager create user that **user must enter A password for Google auth** or **User Must enter a password for Facebook auth**.

From these above error it could be summed up that Django is trying to create a user account immediately upon redirection from social platform.

My first question is should this behavior considered normal, as there might be some complications if the user already has an account.

Second if the behavior is normal, how then should i go about completing the signup process.

```
 File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_django\views.py", line 33, in complete
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\actions.py", line 43, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 40, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py", line 259, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py", line 111, in auth_complete
    return self.do_auth(access_token, response, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py", line 153, in do_auth
    return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_django\strategy.py", line 107, in authenticate
    return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 80, in authenticate
    return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 83, in pipeline
    out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 113, in run_pipeline
    result = func(*args, **out) or {}
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\pipeline\user.py", line 75, in create_user
    'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_core\strategy.py", line 53, in create_user
    return self.storage.user.create_user(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Envs\my_django_environment\lib\site-packages\social_django\storage.py", line 79, in create_user
    user = cls.user_model().objects.create_user(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Desktop\Crackerbox\users\models.py", line 14, in create_user
    raise ValueError("User must enter an email address.")
ValueError: User must enter an email address.
[31/Jan/2019 19:29:32] "GET /oauth/complete/facebook/?granted_scopes=public_profile&denied_scopes&code=AQBt4yAKBum6I8F_XanHwnD-i_9ZTAXhVxOKt0WRQNER7HON2jlO5WTQlmuizKZ0ChI7tJvLT4pp_wLmO5X5gCWAcWqyJYZwyE4UqBJS1WUIL984W-vCawU24M0WsWKW27dhxqAK2ClgXDBTK3YfitvbjdPNEse7dLIBTyNDg926j7IKtQ_dpjsVECmEuAhZOM_vE3TQ5BOElalMxw8laBjWFi_vbhPdPAgFjKtwE3chE_d17n5samw_uamKNmegqYpmX2iZje2xIix56dLZuCvuAwAQaqfYjExgujOe9ZhYE2XHP7M9fG_TYBy-zW1Q8yIFR8iwsCWmQWeLl1jreWvl&state=7UPt8glMyksSPvFzJR4okb1PDvUbgMWK HTTP/1.1" 500 176183
```

Custom user model

```
def create_user(self, email,username, password=None, is_active=True, is_admin= False, is_staff = False, is_profiled =False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must enter an email address.")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must enter a password.")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must enter a username.")
        user_obj = self.model(email= self.normalize_email(email),
        username = username )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.profiled = is_profiled
        user_obj.username = username
        user_obj.save(using= self._db)

        return user_obj
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I get an error". How does this error manifest? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: I added the stack trace.

Comment: The error is raised here: `C:\Users\SAM\Desktop\Crackerbox\users\models.py`. I'm guessing that's code you have written yourself? If you are asking a question about code you wrote, you should include that specific code in the question. [mcve]

Comment: i have also added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `pytjon-social-auth` will create a user automatically if it doesn't detect if the user already has an account on your site.

The error raised is because you are forcing the check for those values on your custom `create_user` method. If those values are required for your normal functionality, then you have a few options:

1. Look if you can add any scope to retrieve them from the auth providers, email is usually available behind one.
2. Use the `partial pipeline` functionality to present the user with a form where the required fields can be filled.

If these fields aren't mandatory for your app, then try removing the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Add request after self, before email

```
def create_user(self, email,username, password=None, is_active=True, is_admin= False, is_staff = False, is_profiled =False):
```